# building a timeline slider in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in the process of building a timeline, but i've run into a bit of a problem with my slider. in the example (UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/WMnsc/3/ ) every time i slide the green div the div "holder" slides in the direction of the green div. the holder div contains a div for each li in the timeline which represents a year.

i'm using multiplication to calculate the speed of the "holder" div so the years line up correctly which is working but what i need is for the sliding to slow down when the green div is sliding over a decade and then resume it's normal speed when it's not.

i've racked my brain a thousand ways from Sunday, but i still can't figure out how to calculate that.

also, if you look at the jsfiddle example you'll see were i was incrementing/de-incrementing based on the direction of the drag. telling which way the slider was going works but the incrementing/de-incrementing based on that was always off..............

Comment: Wait, so the user would be dragging the slider to view different parts of the timeline, but when in the vicinity of one of the decade markers, the whole thing would slow down, as though they were dragging the slider more slowly at those points?

Comment: so you want the timeline to slow down when its hovering over a decade like 2010? Basically your year track will have different widths and you want the boxes to line up with that?

Comment: How about changing the concept slightly. Green-jockey: no change (high gearing for large movements). Additional orange-jockey (eg below the track): low geared for fine movement within the current region set by the green-jockey. On using the green jockey, orange jockey would always be re-centered. This way, you make high resolution scanning available anywhere in the range.

Comment: ultranaut & pim. yeah that's exactly what i need. i feel it can be calculated i just can't seem to figure out how

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot man where were you when they were designing this lol. unfortunately they will not approve any changes to the design since it's been finalized.

Comment: That's just going to get unfortunate for end-users who are trying to whip through the timeline by dragging a handle, where all of a sudden, the handle stops following the mouse and slows down, and then whips back to the mouse position, when it's done squeezing past the decade...  That said, you're probably looking at adding a deceleration (or subtracting by acceleration in the opposite direction), based on a sine-wave which peaks on the 5s and bottoms-out on the 10s.

Comment: @Norguard well in this case the handle wont slow down, just the center div called "holder" that's sliding with all the content. the handle will move at the speed in which it's being dragged.

Comment: I see. And that's fine, I suppose, as long as you add perpetual acceleration to your timeline... So here's my proposition: Take the position of the slider, calculate the percentage of the distance the slider has travelled along the track (already done, in a sense), give the timeline a maximum-speed to animate.  Per animation frame, check if the percentage it's travelled is the same as the slider (round it), otherwise, calculate whether the distance left is higher or lower than max-speed.  From there, run your current position through a sine function, which knows what year you're in...

Comment: ...or, alternatively, if every year is the exact-same width, what your X-position is, in relation to the centre point of a decade's space... Have it spit out a normalized value, which you then scale and subtract from your current update's speed.

Comment: @Norguard i'll be the first to admit i'm a little stumped by your solution. the terminology is a bit above my understanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zero,

They didn't set you an easy task but fortunately this is the sort of thing I really enjoy solving. It took me the best part of a day, and I work quite quickly.

Here's my test page complete with CSS, HTML and javascript - all three are modified versions of your original :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #e0e0c0;
    top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#holder {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: 400px;
}
.boxes {
    position: relative;
    width: 398px;
    height: 400px;
    border-right: 2px solid blue;
    float: left;
}
.year {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
    height: 13px;
    min-width: 8px;
}
.year:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
}
#trackWrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    width: auto;
}
#trackWrapper .track {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    top: 21px;
    width: auto;
}
#trackWrapper .slider1, #trackWrapper .slider2 {
    position:absolute;
}
#trackWrapper .slider1 {
    background-color: green;
    width: 8px;
    height: 20px; 
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#trackWrapper .slider2 {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 12px;
    height: 10px;
    top: 37px;
    left: 220px;
    /* 
    display: none; 
    */
}
#msg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 480px;
    top: 80px;
    height: 1.0em;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
    function log(x){
        var logSwitch = false;
        if(logSwitch) { console.log(x); }
    }

    //Put numbers in the boxes for testing
    $(".boxes").each(function(i) {
        $(this).text(i);
    });

    function courseFineSlider($trackWrapper, $holder, sensitivityDivider) {
        var $slider1 = $trackWrapper.find(".slider1"),
            $slider2 = $trackWrapper.find(".slider2"),
            $track = $trackWrapper.find(".track"),
            $boxes = $(".boxes"),
            $year = $(".year");
        var $slider = null;
        var trackLength = $track.width();// - $year.width() / 2;
        var startX = null;
        var sliderOffSet = null;
        var _pos1 = 0;
        var ePos = 0;

        sensitivityDivider = (!sensitivityDivider) ? 10 : sensitivityDivider;

        $holder.width($boxes.outerWidth() * $boxes.length);
        var holderScale = $boxes.outerWidth() * ($boxes.length - 1);

        function hold(e) {
            log('hold');
            e.preventDefault();
            $slider = $(e.target);
            $(window).on('mousemove', $slider, move);
            startX = e.clientX;
            sliderOffSet = parseInt($slider.css('left'));
            _pos1 = getPos($slider1);
            e.returnValue = false;
        }
        function release(e) {
            if(!$slider) return;
            log('release');
            if($slider.get(0) === $slider2.get(0)) {//if it's the orange slider
                setPos($slider1, ePos);//adjust green according to any movement in orange
                setPos($slider2, 0.5, true);//recenter the orange slider
            }
            $slider = null;
            $(window).off('mousemove');
        }
        function move(e) {
            //console.log('move');
            e.preventDefault();
            var trueSliderX = e.pageX - $trackWrapper.get(0).offsetLeft;
            setPos($slider, applyLimits(0, trueSliderX / trackLength, 1));
            //$holder.css('left', shape(sliderPos()) + 'px'); // *** totally linear ***
            $holder.css('left', -holderScale * shape2(sliderPos()) + 'px'); // *** non-linear - slows down at the decade boundaries ***
        }

        // *** Equations ***
        function sliderPos() {
            var pos1 = getPos($slider1);//green position (0 to 1)
            var pos2 = getPos($slider2);//orange position (0 to 1)
            if($slider.get(0) === $slider1.get(0)) {//if it's the green slider
                ePos = applyLimits(0, (pos1 + (pos2 - 0.5) / sensitivityDivider), 1);
            }
            else {
                ePos = applyLimits(0, (_pos1 + (pos2 - 0.5) / sensitivityDivider), 1);
            }
            return ePos;//effective position of green, taking orange into account
        }

        var LINEAR = function(x1, y1) {//Namespace pattern to keep the $(function(){...}) closure uncluttered
            function Line(m, c) {//Constructor
                this.calc = function(x) {
                    return m * x + c;
                };
            }
            var m1 = y1/x1;
            var m2 = (1-y1)/(1-x1);
            var c1 = 0;
            var c2 = y1 - m2 * x1;
            return {
                x1: x1,
                y1: y1,
                line_1: new Line(m1, c1),
                line_2: new Line(m2, c2)
            };
        }(0.7, 0.90);// change these params as required. 
        /*
     * First param:  Determines the leading edge of the "sluggish zone". 0.7 is about right for the test data.
     * Second param: Determines the height of the two slopes at their intersection. ie. where steep changes to shallow. 
     * Try playing with the second param in the range 0.7 (completely linear) to 0.999999 (comatose). 
     * If the value of the 2nd param is set to something less than the first param, then the "zone" will be more sensitive rather than more sluggish.
         */

        // *** Shaping functions ***
        function shape(x) {
            return x;
        }
        function shape2(x) { //0...1
            var c = 4, //The number of cycles (decades)
                n = x * c,//0...4
                d = Math.floor(n),//"decade" //0, 1, 2, 3, 4
                r = n - d,//remainder //0
                y = (r < LINEAR.x1) ? LINEAR.line_1.calc(r) : LINEAR.line_2.calc(r),
                rtn = (y + d) / c;//unscaled return value
/*
            inspect([
                'x: ' + x.toFixed(2),
                '<br>n: ' + n.toFixed(5),
                '<br>d: ' + d,
                '<br>r: ' + r.toFixed(2),
                '<br>y: ' + y.toFixed(2),
                '<br>rtn: ' + rtn.toFixed(2)]);
*/
            return rtn;
        }

        // *** Utilitiy functions ***
        function applyLimits(min, x, max) {
            return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, x));
        }
        function getPos($sl) {
            return (parseInt($sl.css('left')) + $sl.width() / 2) / trackLength;
        }
        function setPos($sl, val, animate) {
            val = (val * trackLength) - ($sl.width() / 2);
            if(animate) { $sl.animate({left: val}, 'fast'); }
            else { $sl.css({left: val}); }
        }
        function inspect(arr){ //for debugging
            $("#msg").html(arr.join(', '));
        }

        setPos($slider1, 0);//center the green slider
        setPos($slider2, 0.5);//center the orange slider

        $slider1.on('mousedown', hold);
        $slider2.on('mousedown', hold);
        $(window).on('mouseup', release);
    }
    var x = new courseFineSlider($("#trackWrapper"), $('#holder'), 5);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="msg"></div>
<div id="trackWrapper">
    <div class='slider1'></div>
    <div class='slider2'></div>
    <ul class='track'>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'>2000</li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'>2010</li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'>2020</li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'></li>
        <li class='year'>2030</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id='box'>
    <div id="holder">
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJe66/4/show/)**

You will see that I implemented the "sluggish zone" from your design brief AND my orange secondary slider, which is slightly different from my original concept (the arithmetic and variable scoping got rather intense). To run without the orange slider, `#slider2`, simply style it with `display:none` in the style sheet. The javascript doesn't need to be changed. You can reveal Mr Orange one day when the designers realise they made a blooper.

I haven't got time to describe in detail how it works, but there are plenty of comments in the code.

Look below the `LINEAR` namespace towards the bottom of the script for instructions on how to control the position and sensitivity of the "sluggish zone".

Let me know if you need me to explain anything else.

Comment: AWESOME DUDE, this is exactly what i was looking for thanks. i'm like you i love to solve this kind of stuff,but unfortunately this is just one of 3 projects i'm working on (solo developer) and time was running out on this one (bad excuse i know but still)

Comment: i also see you're using a few math concepts i'm not familiar with (or didn't pay enough attention to in school). I'll take this as my motivation to stop dragging my feet and finally learn more math. procrastination with math is a B!T©H i can you that lol

Comment: Zero, the Math is actually quite trivial but the programming was tricky. The clever bit is the `LINEAR` namespace, which does as much as possible up front to minimize the processing load in the move handler.

Comment: One issue you may have is matching up the decade zones with particular content in the boxes. This is a black art I'm afraid. As it stands, the code makes no attempt to achieve this automatically so your best approach would need to be to empirical (ie. trial and error).

Comment: i do have one question. is the code dependent on the orange slider? in other words is the sliderPos function the only one to be reworked to use just the green slider or will i have to change majority of the other functions as well?

Comment: of course of course, my attempt is to dissect and understand the code a lot better than i do. and in doing so i was wondering for the green slider to do what it does (precise calculations, sluggish zones, etc..) there has to be a second slider to achieve this? even if it's not used nor seen the green slider still needs it for calc purposes?

Comment: Ok, `$slider2` is not germane to the sluggish zone calcs which are performed by `shape2()` together with objects in the `LINEAR` namespace, none of which addresses $slider2. However, `sliderPos()` (probably not well named) reads both `$slider1` and `$slider2` positions to calculate the "effective position" (ePos) of `$slider1` taking both sliders into account, regardless of which one is actually being moved. In this regard, `$slider2` is inherent to `move` event handling, but not to the sluggish shaping *per se*.

Comment: The key statement is `$holder.css('left', -holderScale * shape2(sliderPos()) + 'px');` in the `move` handler which coordinates all the calcs to ensure the `$holder` is correctly positioned. As long as `$slider2` exists and is centered at 0.5, it has no bearing on the position of `$holder`. The amount of additional processing required to cater for `$slider2` is minimal so it's not worth trying to remove all the `$slider2` stuff if you don't use it; just make sure it's centered and style it with `display:none`.